# Remove words of length less than 4 from string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove words of length less than 4 from a string.

I use this regex:

```
 re.sub(' \w{1,3} ', ' ', c)
```

Though this removes some strings but it fails when 2-3 words of length less than 4 appear together. Like:

```
 I am in a bank.
```

It gives me:

```
 I in bank.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You are removing words of *up to 10 characters*; not 3. If you want to remove words *less than length 4*, why the `{1, 10}` qualification?

Comment: if you want to remove words of length less than four means then why you give `{1,10}`?

Comment: Sorry about the error. Edited the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't include the spaces; use `\b` word boundary anchors instead:

```
re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b', '', c)
```

This removes words of up to 3 characters entirely:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b', '', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
' quick brown  jumps over  lazy '
>>> re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b', '', 'I am in a bank.')
'    bank.'
```

Comment: `r'\b\w{,3}\b'` would be a shorter one.

Comment: Is it possible to remove extra spaces before bank?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: sure, there is not 1-character `\w` match that would work between `\b` boundaries. I was trying to stay a little closer to the OP expression.

Comment: @wannaC: that makes the expression much more complicated; we can remove an optional space *after* each word, or *before* each word, but to handle this properly would need to a use `r'(?:\b\w{,3}\s|\s\w{,3}\b|\b\w{,3}\b)'` three-parter.

Comment: How to put variable to replace number 3?
re.sub(r'\b\w{1,variable}\b', '', c)?

Comment: @PhokChanrithisak: use a string template; `r"\b\w{1,%d}\b" % (variable,)` perhaps.

Answer (score 8):

If you want an alternative to regex:

```
new_string = ' '.join([w for w in old_string.split() if len(w)>3])
```

Comment: ```$ python -mtimeit -s'import pytest' 'pytest.plain()'
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.36 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import pytest' 'pytest.reg_ex()'
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.6 usec per loop``` this version is much faster then with reg ex

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Martijn, but I just wanted to explain why your regex doesn't work. The regex string `' \w{1,3} '` matches a space, followed by 1-3 word characters, followed by another space. The `I` doesn't get matched because it doesn't have a space in front of it. The `am` gets replaced, and then the regex engine starts at the next non-matched character: the `i` in `in`. It doesn't see the space before `in`, since it was placed there by the substitution. So, the next match it finds is `a`, which produces your output string.